# Using blockchain_parser to parse blk files stored on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, filesystems, expanduser

I'm trying to use alecalve's bitcoin-parser pkg for python.
The problem is, my node is saved on an s3 bucket.
As the parser uses os.path.expanduser for the .dat files dir, expecting a filesystem, I can't just use my s3 path. The example from the documentation is:

```
import os
from blockchain_parser.blockchain import Blockchain


blockchain = Blockchain(os.path.expanduser('~/.bitcoin/blocks'))
for block in blockchain.get_ordered_blocks(os.path.expanduser('~/.bitcoin/blocks/index'), end=1000):
    print("height=%d block=%s" % (block.height, block.hash))
```

And the error I'm getting is as follows:

```
'name' arg must be a byte string or a unicode string
```

Is there a way to use s3fs or any different s3-to-filesystem method to use the s3 paths as dirs for the parser to work as intended?

Comment: Not a chance.  blockchain_parser uses memory-mapped files to read the file, it needs a file that can be mapped.  You _might_ be able to use s3fs

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much my question, if and how I could use s3fs in that manner.